# Getting 400 Bad Request when send large JSON data to WCF ReST service

Tags: wcf

I did all correct setting on the service, but still get the same stupid 400 Bad Request when I try to PUT a large amount JSON data to my WCF REST service. Below is my service Web.config.  I'm struggling with this for 3 weeks already and found no answer.  This is the exception detail from the response:

> "There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type BuildStepResource. The
>   maximum string content length quota
>   (8192) has been exceeded while reading
>   XML data. This quota may be increased
>   by changing the MaxStringContentLength
>   property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used
>   when creating the XML reader."

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="nonSSLBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" >
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
                    </security>
                    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
                </binding>
                <binding name="sslBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" >
                    <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
                    </security>
                    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" name="serviceEndpoints">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ISWCRestService" bindingConfiguration="nonSSLBinding" behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior"/>
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ISWCRestService" bindingConfiguration="sslBinding" behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior"/>
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IXmlEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="nonSSLBinding" behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior"/>
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IXmlEndpoint" bindingConfiguration="sslBinding" behaviorConfiguration="customBehavior"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="webBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="customBehavior">
                    <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" helpEnabled="true"/>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? I have been facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

The error message refers to a quota being exceeded while *reading* which makes me believe that you need to increase the MaxStringContentLength property on the *client* side, other than on your web.config.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I've tried with max integer maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647", but still getting the same error.

Comment: The changes need to be made at the client. Create a client app instead of just using the browser and give it a try.

Comment: Thanks! Tried with client app as suggested, but still getting the same error.  I did some traces, and found that the exception is on the server, not the client.  Here is my client config:

Comment: <configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
           <webHttpBinding>
               <binding name="ClientBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                   <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a WCF client.  You have to configure MaxItemsInObjectGraph to be larger on your client and on your server.  I don't know how to do this in JSON.

Comment: I did that on the server, but still didn't work.  How do I do this on the Client if I use REST Client for FireFox to test? Or how do I set this if I call the PUT in a jQuery script?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Client side config -

```
<binding name="yourBinding"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
</binding>
```

Comment: <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
       <bindings>
           <webHttpBinding>
               <binding name="ClientBinding" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                   <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
               </binding>
           </webHttpBinding>
       </bindings>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Comment: Try to change to WSHttpBinding

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your web.config:

```
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
    </system.web>
```